# Is model necessary in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

The document says that in model you can connect with sql and do something to manage, but in the controller I can also load the database and connect with sql to manage these things too, I know in 
traditional MVC you will like model, so I just want to know if it's necessary to use model in CI.

Comment: If you *can* access the database from the controller then obviously the model is not *necessary*. If you really like shooting yourself in the foot, it's also not necessary.

Comment: Necessary? No, but you also don't need to use the controller. Just load php files in your view.

Comment: [what is mvc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: CI loosely follow MVC. It is not necessary to use model.

Answer (score 3):

As other have pointed out, models are NOT necessary; neither is using ANY framework.  We choose to use frameworks because they provide a number of tools and design practices that makes developing easier.  One of these is the seperation of presentation and logic.

Logic in MVC is generally performed by Models.  Controllers only handle receiving input and invoking the correct models.  This allows you to easily test your code.  This also allows you to concurrently and separately develop front end and backend code.

I think it is important to [read](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) about the MVC design pattern to learn what it is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Unless and until you are not interacting with your `Database` actions you don't need model and ofcorse in some cases you `can write your database queries at controller itself`.But it is **meaningless** of using `MVC` (Model View Controller) architecture.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can load and make the model's operations also in controller but that it isn't MVC pattern.

MVC (model-view-controller) is a pattern through which you can separate the three "logical sector".

For example:
Supposing that you have to select a product list more times in more pages (menaged by controller), without the model you should re-write the query for each controller and this code-repeat lie outside the MVC pattern, going beyond the bad performances.
Morover by the model, you can menage easly the persistent data.

MVC pattern was "created" for write less code end re-use the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to know that Models are not only for databases, but are more oriented to that function.

A model is where you define the interactions with the persistent information, it can be a file, a database, a filesystem, etc.

It is not strictly necessary to have one, but HIGHLY recommended if you need to persist information (save/read), because it divides the application into logic parts. (MODEL - VIEW - CONTROLLER). Each has it function.